# Should this question be really closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I don't see this question about [*Omission of if in a conditional phrase*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572267/omission-of-if-in-a-conditional-phrase/572268#572268) as being the duplicate of *[Must conditional sentences begin with “if?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48819/must-conditional-sentences-begin-with-if)*. Yet this is the stated reason for the closure of the question. The answer of the supposed duplicate is scarce and does not deal with subjunctive really. Also, the closed question has a second query that has just been glossed over as non-existent. Is that on?

Are we not too quick to close? Just wondering...

Comment: Wouldn't this be better dealt with by editing the question (so as to make it clear why it is not a duplicate), or posting a comment to it (giving one's reasons for its not being a duplicate), rather than by raising a separate meta-question about it? Whatever one thinks about whether that question should have been closed, it doesn't seem that its closing illustrates any general problems with the functioning of the site.

Comment: Once I did so, and I was told to post my request for opening the question on Meta.

Comment: @jsw29 Meta is a very appropriate place to make a longer case and request for reopen votes. Of course, your suggestion about editing and commenting is also good. But also we are probably too quick to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it is not a full duplicate. The older question only covers part of this question. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I am glad someone agrees... Similarity should not be enough grounds to dismiss a question. Thank you.